# libgnutls.so.26 no such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, emacs, libraries, debian-jessie

I upgrade my Debian jessie and, when I try to open Emacs, It send me this error:

**`emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libgnutls.so.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`**

I try to install it by apt, but cannot find the file. Only `28` is availlable.
How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that your emacs wasn't installed through apt but was compiled from source, or is from a separate repository. Either way you'll need to reinstall it (and maybe find a different repository).

Comment: Yes, i didn't install emacs24 from apt. So i remove it and install it from apt.
I hope solved the issue.

Comment: actually I have this file located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26

So maybe the symbolic link is losted ?